# Should [charts] and [graphs] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-cleanup-request

[charts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charts) - 205 questions tagged / 77% answered.

[graphs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphs) - 148 questions tagged / 79% answered.

Both [charts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charts) & [graphs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphs) - [27 tagged with both](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charts+graphs?sort=newest&pagesize=30) / 74% answered

I think the real difference between [charts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charts) and [graphs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphs) is so technical and nuanced that there is no practical difference in how most users (myself included) view them.

**EDIT:** Here's a current example where the [question](https://superuser.com/questions/604145/excel-graph-pulls-fine-for-one-user-but-adds-years-to-x-axis-maximum-for-anothe) is tagged [charts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charts) but references "graphs" throughout the question.

Should they be merged or made synonyms?

Comment: If we were to merge them, what would you suggest to be the merge target (as in, the tag that remains alive)?

Comment: [Charts] has a slight edge in count, and matches Excel terminology, which is where many of the questions come from, so that'd be my recommendation.

Comment: [Charts] sounds like maps to me, and possibly also tables (despite what Microsoft says).  I think [Graphs] has the more uniform meaning across different people.  Of course, [Charts-Graphs] or [Graphs-Charts] might be best (especially if the tag system would suggest the former after typing "gra", or the latter after typing "cha".

Comment: This is an old, but I still think valid tag clean-up issue.  I've re-tagged based upon the discussion here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8123/a-new-way-to-clean-up-tags?cb=1

Comment: When somebody uses "graphs" correctly, please let them use it: http://superuser.com/questions/516516/interactive-graph-visualization?noredirect=1#comment1071259_516516

In no way a data struture with nodes and edges can ever be called a "graph".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Wikipedia terminology:

- **chart**: A chart is a graphical representation of data, in which "the data is represented by symbols, such as bars in a bar chart, lines in a line chart, or slices in a pie chart".
- **graph**: Information graphics or infographics are graphic visual representations of information, data or knowledge intended to present complex information quickly and clearly.

Thus, I propose to merge (and synonymize) into [chart](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chart).

During cleanup, I would propose to replace [graph](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graph) with [chart](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chart) where appropriate. In cases there [graph](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graph) is used to refer to non-chart type graphs, use a different tag or just remove it.