# A new way to clean up tags

Tags: discussion, tags

#### This is the proposal. Please see [Help us clean up tags!](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8146/help-us-clean-up-tags) for the result.

---

Let's face it, we have [tons](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/open) [of](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disable) [horrible](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/delete) [tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/menus).

In the past, we used [Old monthly tag cleanups](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-june-2014) to keep track of what needs to be cleaned up. But I see a couple of problems with this approach lately.

1. Random users just edit the question itself and add tags to the cleanup list without going through any proper procedure.
2. Users keep posting answers to that question containing tags they would like to see cleaned up.
3. It's *really* hard to keep track of the whole process.

What's *supposed* to happen is that tags are discussed in separate questions and when consensus regarding removal of the tag is reached, it gets added to the list. Lately, this process isn't happening at all. So here is my proposal:

1. [Old monthly tag cleanups](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-june-2014) gets closed, protected, locked and deleted.
2. When someone discovers a [horrible](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/environment) [tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/save), they post a new question on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/) about it, tagging it with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) in combination with [tag-cleanup-request](/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup-request).

   The request will then be discussed (or ignored) but, most importantly, voted on and after a week (give or take) a **moderator** will tag the question with:

   - [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) if the proposal was denied
   - [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) if the proposal was accepted
3. Any question that is tagged with [tag-cleanup-request](/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup-request) and [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) [(here's a handy link to the search)](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/status-planned+tag-cleanup-request) can be acted upon by anyone in the community.
4. Once a tag is cleaned up, the [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag is replaced with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: I would much rather see a "review" type of automated, or semi-automated audit process for cleaning up bad tags, as a feature of the site.

Comment: @sammyg So would I. Don't hold your breath though ;P

Comment: The only issue I see with this is making the cleanup requests accessible easily. Like now, the bulletin nicely links to the cleanup post. So would we need a list of planned cleanup-requests? (A Meta-Meta question with links to Meta-questions?)

Comment: Couldn't a mod just compile the list of status-planned tag removals in a monthly post that is protected/locked? That would avoid random user edits, but it would still keep the tag cleanup process easily accessible to all users.

Comment: I kind of like @Excellll idea. That gives a central repository to do stuff, and at the same time allow separated discussion.

Comment: If tags were supposed to be discussed in separate questions, then there was no need for a tag cleanup post then! Moderators could simply *burninate* the tag without need for manual cleanup!

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi No, we can't. We have to go through every single question and remove the tag just like everyone else. Tags used to be discussed in separate questions, some users might have never realized that though and lately nobody seems to be doing it anymore.

Comment: The advantages of having a tag cleanup post is that the community could add **non-controversial** tags to the post for housekeeping. Potentially controversial tags would go in a separate question. Therefore, I think we should **keep the tag cleanup, but use it only for non-controversial tags that need removal for housekeeping purposes.** This method seems perfect, but it assumes that all tags being removed are potentially controversial.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Who decides which tags are controversial? If you have alternative suggestions (or don't want to change anything at all), please post it as an answer. Long discussions in comment threads are not useful.

Comment: Tags with lots of questions tagged seem more controversial to me, while tags with very few questions seem more like non-controversial removals. I'll post an answer in a moment. (See the new categorization I've added to that post.)

Comment: Does the tag need to have so horrible as in your examples or can it be something lighter? I'm asking because I wanted to propose replacing **redhat** with **rhel** where appropriate.

Comment: Interesting how the community works together. But where is the place that tells the people "Let's do it!"? I already see this being used http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup-request. Where is the list of SOP? I am interested to have a look is it is public :) Thanks.

Comment: @Jake From the question: _Any question that is tagged with [tag:tag-cleanup-request] and [tag:status-planned] (here's a [handy link](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/status-planned+tag-cleanup-request) to the search) can be acted upon by anyone in the community._

Comment: can we change the tag name to `tag-burnination-request` since it's more widely know term.

Comment: @Braiam I thought you were joking, that's why I removed your initial comment suggesting the term. The cleanup does not imply "burnination" of a tag and the term has merely meme status for me. So I'm not in favor of using that suggestion.

Comment: Through cleanup doesn't imply it, most of them will be about burning some or other tag, so we may as well comply with the tag naming. Also, it would help the CM team to find questions like this, that they can just act on them.

Comment: @Braiam [meta-tag:burninate-request] was what was used on MSO.

Comment: We could use the blog as a means for the "meta-meta" posting for the month.  That way it appears on the bulletin, and is limited to those with publishing power (which is entirely made of mods and myself) to post to the site.

Comment: I do believe that most of the problems here would have been fixed by wikilocking ("*This question's answer is a collaborative effort; if you see something that can be improved, just edit to improve it! No additional answers can be added here*") the old post (preventing non-mods from editing it and preventing new answers without having to resort to closure). However, this new procedure is better than the old one on several *other* respects.

Answer (score -3):

Personally, I think that the current tag cleanup process used for a long time now seems perfect for non-controversial removals of little-used or newly-created tags that should be removed preemptively to avoid future problems. However, it was not so useful for tags with lots of questions tagged and whose removals would be very controversial. slhck and I came up with a new procedure for sorting out tags in the former category and in the latter category.

My (counter-)proposal is this, which makes big modifications to the existing tag cleanup based on ideas established in the question:

### TL;DR

Tags whose removal **wouldn't** be debated *for sure* will go through as before. Tags whose removal **would** be debated or tags in which the one who finds the tag doesn't know what would happen would be posted as a separate question, and then if the consensus is to clean up, would be added to the tag cleanup.

### Long version

#### What should be done now:

There are now two lists in the main answer ("uncovered in the audit") to the existing tag cleanup: one with little-used or newly-created tags whose removal would not be very controversial, and one with tags that have lots of questions tagged each whose removal would be more controversial and debated. Each tag from the latter list should be subject to the procedure currently outlined in the question for community consensus, and if the decision was to clean up, it should remain in the list, and if the decision was not to clean up, it should be removed from the list.

#### What should be done in the future:

If you think the removal of a tag would not be very controversial (rule of thumb: less than 200 questions tagged (though that's a ridiculously simple heuristic that may need to be changed)), it should be added directly to the answer in the first list. If you think that the removal of a tag would be potentially controversial (rule of thumb: 200 or more questions tagged) **or if you're not sure**, it should be posted here as a question following the procedure outlined here. Again, if it meets community consensus, it will be added to the second list, and if not, will not be added at that moment.

Other than this, the tag cleanup will work as it has always been, except that moderators should add the same number of tags from each list into the question (I think two each is a good number).

Personally, I feel like the existing procedure favored the non-controversial tags, while this new one favors the controversial tags. My idea takes ideas from both and creates a very good procedure that works for both kinds of tags.

One last question: What will we do to prevent users from adding their own favorite tags to the post? We'll say that all edits that add tags to the second list must link to the decision to clean up in the edit summary, and all edits that add tags to the first list must have less questions tagged. If the respective criteria aren't met, the edit will be rolled back.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't disagree, but the approach we used before (list of tags, discussion about it in some comments, promoting into the question) wasn't really efficient. So we need to keep the discussion for each tag separate, not in one comment thread. Even if they might seem trivial. If they are indeed trivial and no discussion is needed, they can be be `[status-planned]` right away.

Comment: @slhck That's what I said! We'll discuss in separate questions. Why did you think I was talking about comments?

Comment: @slhck Tags whose removal **wouldn't** be debated *for sure* will go through as before. Tags whose removal **would** be debated or tags in which the one who finds the tag doesn't know what would happen would be posted as a separate question, and then if the consensus is to clean up, would be added to the tag cleanup.