# Replace the `Surface` tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-cleanup-request

Users having a Microsoft Surface Computer/Tablet are using the [microsoft-surface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface) tag. But I also find some questions having just [surface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/surface), which does not have a lot to do with the Microsoft Surface Tablets.

So how should we proceed?

1. Edit the questions and change the [surface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/surface) tag to [tag:Microsoft Surface] seems obvious
2. But do we need to add tag synonyms between them?
3. There is a third type of tags [surface-pro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/surface-pro) which points to a specific type of Surface (though the [surface-rt](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/surface-rt) tag has not been used yet). Should that be a synonym too?
   \

Comment: I propose to add a synonym from [surface] to [microsoft-surface] and merge the three questions.

Comment: I need to check this out for myself, but I recall there was a question for the old, table sized surface as well. We might need to split that off post merge if we did.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What was the table-top "Surface" has been renamed to [PixelSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PixelSense), if there were any questions regarding it specifically then I'd create a tag and move them over but as there isn't...

Comment: @slhck meh, there were only 3 question. No need to bring the bazookas.

Comment: @Braiam Not sure what you mean. What's bad about adding such a synonym?

Comment: @slhck well, that technically surface has 2 more meanings that are unrelated to the microsoft surface produce, one is geometric, and the other is a movie and I see little gain in doing so.

Comment: @Braiam We are not a site for mathematics and geometrics, so a surface tag related to geometrical surfaces would not make sense. Likewise, we would need to have `[microsoft-windows]` instead of `[windows]` because somebody might think it's about those square things you have in your wall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [surface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/surface) has been cleaned, merged and synonymized → [microsoft-surface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface).
- [surface-pro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/surface-pro) has been merged and synonymized → [microsoft-surface-pro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface-pro) for consistency.