# Tag cleanup suggestion: [copy]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Description of [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) is "Questions about copying in the context of file managemenent and backing up."

Okay we have another tag [file-copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) which serve more or less the same purpose; we have [xcopy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xcopy) [robocopy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/robocopy) [copy-protection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy-protection) for specific areas.  Seems [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) is duplicated.

The worse thing is [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) is misused by some questions that is about copying contents within/across applications.  Nothing wrong without looking at the description of the tag; but that makes it too generic and not meaningful when using alone.  Therefore suggest to migrate [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) to [file-copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) and then remove [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy).

Answer (score 5):

I agree, really, a lot of questions which use `copy` tag are in low quality.
(I just clicked on tag and checked the first page of questions.)
But there are some obstacles:

- A lot of Excel questions (like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/786069/copy-from-sheet2-to-sheet1-based-on-if-values-match),[this](https://superuser.com/questions/713069/excel-how-can-i-copy-cell-contents-from-multiple-sheets-at-once),[this](https://superuser.com/questions/790003/how-do-you-copy-the-value-from-one-cell-in-one-worksheets-to-two-cells-in-consec)...) where `copy` is not related to `file-copy` (yes, you mentioned them as "The worse thing...").
- Issues with `copy` command in command line (like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/766334/batch-copy-gives-errors-xcopy-works-fine) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/770829/copy-a-copy-b-use-of-this-options)), where `file-copy` tag will be more generic and `xcopy` and `robocopy` can not replace it.
- And a new software called [Copy](http://www.copy.com) cloud storage ([this](https://superuser.com/questions/790613/usage-reported-by-copy-app-is-a-lot-less-than-actual-usage) question).

Adding a tag like `copy-app` or `copy-cloud-storage` can somehow solve problem with Copy cloud.

But what to do with that Excel questions?
Add new tags like `excel-copy` or `copy-in-excel`? Leaving these questions without `copy` is not a good idea, and replacing them with `file-copy` is wrong - a big headache.

Comment: Agrees that lots of Excel questions used [copy] tag for content-copying purpose.  However [copy] tag has 2 out of 4 criteria that requires cleanup: (1) The tag is only useful when it's combined with another tag; (2) The tag could mean different things, depending on context. For that reason I think [copy] is to be removed; adding [excel-copy] [copy-cloud-storage] could be created if there are sufficient similar questions.  {Ref: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8146/help-us-clean-up-tags?cb=1}

Comment: Just to chime in here, there isn't a `file` or `file-copy` tag, which could be applicable to questions like this (as file transfer isn't really applicable to this question):  http://superuser.com/questions/742515/recursive-non-overwriting-file-copy

Comment: Just an opinion, but not every nuance needs a tag.  For uses like copying a cell range in Excel, a copy-related tag isn't needed and could simply be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since Dropped.on.Caprica's comment is, seemingly, being ignored,
I'm escalating it to an "answer"
(although I'm wondering whether it should be a new question). 
The tag cleanup that was requested and moderator-approved here was

> ... migrate [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) to [file-copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) ...

But the is no [file-copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) tag on Super User. 
Questions tagged [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) (that refer to copying files)
are being coerced into [file-transfer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer). 
This is not necessarily relevant to questions about local file copying
(e.g., [Recursive, Non-Overwriting File Copy](https://superuser.com/q/742515/354511))
or copy protection (e.g., [Prevent users from copying files in a directory](https://superuser.com/q/434849/354511)).

Why aren't we doing this tag cleanup the way it was approved? 
Why don't we have a [file-copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) tag?

Comment: [file-copying is a synonym of file-transfer](http://superuser.com/tags/file-transfer/synonyms)

Comment: "file-transfer" is NOT "file-copying". By default "file transfer" itself is referred as "file move operation".  And "move" and "copy" are different things, so it would be nice to see them separated.