# Removing the [unlock] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [unlock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unlock) tag seems to meet all the criteria for a tag that should be removed - per the [recent tag-cleanup initiative](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8146/216882):

> If the tag falls into any of these categories, it should probably be removed or replaced:
>
> ```
> * The tag is only useful when it's combined with another tag. Like [update], [install] or [task].
>
> * The tag does not describe a specific technology or area of expertise. Like [color], [temporary] or [file].
>
> * The tag could mean different things, depending on context. Like [environment], [noise] or [terminal].
>
> * The tag describes an extremely broad topic. Like [software], [technology] or [equipment].
> ```

No questions have been tagged [unlock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unlock), and the tag's wiki is empty.

Can anyone offer a good reason to keep it?

Comment: That's a synonym of the unused tag [tag:unlocking].

Comment: Thanks for not making the question title a pun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system will show up the page you mention for any term, doesn't mean they exist in the system. For now nothing needs to be done

Comment: Please clarify what you mean - "The system will show up the page you mention for any term".  I just went to the Tags page, sorted (descendingly) by popularity, and went to the last results page: there was [unlock].

Comment: [tag:j0e3gan] is not a valid tag but visiting the link shows as if it's a valid tag.

Comment: Okay, that is interesting...but not what I did.  [J0e3gan] is not listed in the [Tags](http://superuser.com/tags) page; [unlock] is.

Comment: Unused tags are regularly pruned. At this moment there's nothing to be done

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Thanks for clarifying.