# You're fired: Burn the [position] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[position](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/position) seems quite meta - no useful description, and no consistency, and it will not help experts in "positioning" find questions, in my opinion. I vote to fire it

Comment: I am unsure of my [tag:position] on this issue...

Comment: For most of the tagged questions, [position] doesn't add value.  A few might benefit from replacing the tag with [layout].

Comment: @Flyk Please do not start cleaning up a tag until the tag cleanup request post has been marked as [status-planned] by a moderator. For more info on the tag cleanup process see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8123/a-new-way-to-clean-up-tags

Comment: @Excellll sometimes, the issue is so obvious that you don't have to wait for a moderator (or even write a meta post about it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Done

Tag removed from all questions.

Several questions asked about window positions. For these questions, I used [window](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/window) in place of [position](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/position), which isn't very meaningful as it fails to specify any particular topic and is therefore a meta-tag.

Action taken on strong community consensus, as indicated by the question score. Waiting for moderator approval in cases like these, where the question has a high score (>= 15) and no downvotes or objecting answers, is IMO nothing more than red tape.