# Do we need the [scattergraph] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

With only 10 questions and no follower or tag summary, [scattergraph](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scattergraph) seems a good case for deletion and, when possible, replacing with the more frequented [graphs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphs) or [chart](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chart) tag whenever needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm proposing to just merge it into [graphs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphs) and let it be sorted out together with [Should [charts] and [graphs] tags be merged?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6841/should-charts-and-graphs-tags-be-merged)